# Where to place non-conflicting libraries for program on Linux?

Tags: linux, deployment, installation, shared-libraries

I want to place some shared libraries specific to a program which might conflict with existing libraries if placed in /usr/lib or whatever. Where should I put them so they are specific to the program? Also the program is configured to use shared libraries and I don' have time to change that, so I want to use shared libraries thank you.

Would I be right by creating a folder in /usr/lib for the program such as /usr/lib/myprog/somelib.so?

I'll add the folder to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

The problem I have is some libraries with the same soname are incompatible (stupid I know). I can't risk conflicts occurring.

Comment: you can use /usr/local/lib, which is the location intended for user libraries.

Comment: For a program named `foo` you might consider a `/usr/libexec/foo/` or a `/usr/local/libexec/foo/` directory. Otherwise, refer to the [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

Comment: I'm not sure that usr/local is the best place since this is a release build.

Comment: Apparently libexec is for executable programs and not libraries?